# Content Security Policy (CSP) sha256 mistmatch in Chrome 74.x but works fine in in Chrome 75.x

Tags: google-chrome, javascript

I'm trying to set a very strict Content Security Policy (CSP) on my site as follows:

> `base-uri 'self';script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'report-sample' https: http: 'sha256-lfXlPY3+MCPOPb4mrw1Y961+745U3WlDQVcOXdchSQc=' 'sha256-rRMdkshZyJlCmDX27XnL7g3zXaxv7ei6Sg+yt4R3svU=' 'nonce-[CSP-NONCE]' 'Strict-Dynamic' 'unsafe-hashes';frame-src 'self';object-src 'none';report-uri /report-csp;`

But I find that, in Chrome/74.0.3729.169, the `sha256-lfXlPY3+MCPOPb4mrw1Y961+745U3WlDQVcOXdchSQc=` does not match the script 'javascript:;'.

I know it work works in Chrome/75.x

The report from Chrome/74.0.3729.169 like follows:

> `{"csp-report":{"document-uri":"https://xxx.xxx.com/","referrer":"https://xxx.xxx.com/","violated-directive":"script-src-elem","effective-directive":"script-src-elem","original-policy":"base-uri 'self';script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'report-sample' https: http: 'sha256-lfXlPY3+MCPOPb4mrw1Y961+745U3WlDQVcOXdchSQc=' 'sha256-rRMdkshZyJlCmDX27XnL7g3zXaxv7ei6Sg+yt4R3svU=' 'nonce-ICXBmlKCIhrG35lflJLb' 'Strict-Dynamic' 'unsafe-hashes';frame-src 'self';object-src 'none';report-uri /report-csp;","disposition":"report","blocked-uri":"inline","line-number":1,"source-file":"https://xxx.xxx.com/","status-code":0,"script-sample":"javascript:;"}}`

Is that a bug in Chrom 74.x?

FWIW, another hash in the policy works both in Chrome 74.x and Chrome 75.x.`('sha256-rRMdkshZyJlCmDX27XnL7g3zXaxv7ei6Sg+yt4R3svU=' means 'javascript:void(0)')`

The user agent for the browser is:

> `user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36 –`